# Delete set of duplicate records and Keep another set of duplicate record

Tags: sql, t-sql

Please see data given below
[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1980/deleteduprecords.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/1980/deleteduprecords.png)

I want to keep one set of records and want to delete another duplicate set of records. You can see ForeignKey are same just Primary Key is different.

Need to keep 2 records having lowest primary key among the set of 4 records.

Comment: how do you know which records to keep and which not to ?

Comment: do you mean you wish to keep the 2 records with the lowest primary key where there are duplicates on the ForeignKey + AnotherForeignKey rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Delete from Table mytable t1
where exists (select 1 from mytable t2
where t2.PrimaryKey < t1.PrimaryKey
and t2.ForeignKey = t1.ForeignKey
and t2.AnotherForeignKey = t1.AnotherForeignKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE functionality from SQL Server 2005, you can delete Duplicate records as follows

**(PS. I cannot see the design, so this is an approach.)**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        FK INT,
        VName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 1, 1, 'A'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 2, 1, 'A'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 3, 1, 'A'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 4, 2, 'B'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 5, 2, 'B'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,FK,VName) SELECT 6, 2, 'B'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FK  ORDER BY ID) RowNumber
    FROM    @Table
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am in a dilema that whether by SET you mean to say a combination of all the last 2 fields or only the foreign key.

If it is only foreign Key, accept Astender's solution.

If it is for last two fields, then

**Sample input:**

```
PK  FK  AFK
4669    121 1
4670    121 2
10675   121 1
10676   121 2
101 254 1
102 254 2
703 254 1
704 254 2
```

**Query:**

```
;with cte as(
select
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by FK ,AFK order by GETDATE()) rn,
t.* from @t t)
delete from cte where rn = 1
select * from @T
```

**Output:**

```
PK  FK  AFK
4669    121 1
10676   121 2
102 254 2
703 254 1
```